# Can it be proven that any Lipschitz function is uniformly continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

I know that a function is Lipschitz if $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|$. However, I'm not sure how I would create the proof using this information.

Comment: choose $\delta = \epsilon / M $

Comment: A comparison with the definition of "uniformly continuous" should immediately show some similarity.

Comment: "Yes, it can." (The title of this question is... baffling. What would be the alternative -- mathematicians have been lying for the past 100 years?)

Comment: @ClementC.: it is obvious to me that a Lipschitz function is uniformly continuous. That doesn't mean that I recall seeing the statement explicitly. For some reason you assume that the OP saw the statement and doesn't believe it. Most likely, the OP (same as me) never so the statement written anywhere.

Comment: @MartinArgerami TBH, I didn't even think of that. I assumed every teacher, when introducing these concepts, would automatically mention (if not prove) how they are related. Not doing so seems even more baffling, and can only confuse the students in the middle or long term.

Comment: @ClementC.: I definitely agree. I was just suggesting that it may not be the case. Personally, I don't really recall when/how I was introduced to the notion of Lipschitz, so I cannot really say if my teacher/book did it or not.

Answer (score 3):

For $\varepsilon > 0$ choose $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{M}$. Then $|x - y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$.